# throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('first argument', nodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am having the following error and do not understan why. My objective is to do a post request when triggering a firebase function however I am getting an really weird error.

I am trying to do a post request in nodeJs and firebase however it gives me the following error:

```
    functions: Beginning execution of "Klarna"
    ⚠  External network resource requested!
       - URL: "https://api.playground.klarna.com/payments/v1/sessions"
     - Be careful, this may be a production service.
    >  _http_outgoing.js:661
    >      throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('first argument',
    >      ^
    >  
    >  TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer. Received an instance of Object
    >      at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:661:11)
    >      at ClientRequest.write (_http_outgoing.js:629:15)
    >      at Request.write (/Users/pedromiguell/Work/Nortb/8. software/foliepapper/node_modules/request/request.js:1494:27)
    >      at end (/Users/pedromiguell/Work/Nortb/8. software/foliepapper/node_modules/request/request.js:549:18)
    >      at Immediate._onImmediate (/Users/pedromiguell/Work/Nortb/8. software/foliepapper/node_modules/request/request.js:578:7)
    >      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21) {
    >    code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
    >  }
```

this is the function:

```
exports.Klarna = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const creds = req.body
    const Headers = () => {
            const token = `Basic  ${Buffer.from(
              `${"xxx"}:${"xxx"}`
            ).toString("base64")}`;
            return {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
              Authorization: token,
            };
          };

    const url = "https://api.playground.klarna.com/payments/v1/sessions"

    request("https://api.playground.klarna.com/payments/v1/sessions", {
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        headers: Headers,
        body: creds
    },
        function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log(body)
            }
        }
    )
})
```

Answer (score -1):

solved it

```
exports.Klarna = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const url = "https://api.playground.klarna.com/payments/v1/sessions";
  const creds = req.body;
  const token = `Basic  ${Buffer.from(
    `${"xxx"}:${"xxx"}`
  ).toString("base64")}`;

  request(
    "https://api.playground.klarna.com/payments/v1/sessions",
    {
      method: "POST",
      url: url,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        Authorization: token,
      },
      Authorization: token,
      body: creds,
      json: true,
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
      }
    }
  );
});
```